# Memoir contents spacing for section number

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, memoir

In a table of contents set with Memoir I have the problem that the spacing between the Section name and the section umber is too small when section numbers are larger than 9:

[image]

Based on page 150 of the `memman.pdf` I got the feeling that `\cftKindent` controlled that space ("This length controls the indentation of an entry from the left margin (indent in Figure 9.2). It can be changed using `\setlength`.") but when I try to change it with `\setlength\cftKnumwidth{3em}` I get:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cftKnumwidth 

l.445 \setlength\cftKnumwidth{3em}

?
```

What am I missing? How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The K in `\cftKnumnwidth` is a variable used in the documentation. Replace K with `section` for (for section).  See Table 9.3 of the documentation for other possible values.

[image]

Memoir also uses a similar scheme for section formatting commands (indents, before skips, etc.) The documentation variable in this case is S, e.g. `\setbeforeSskip` sets the skip before a heading of type S, where S can be `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph` or `subparagraph`.